# Parentheses in (named) SQL query stall whole application - why?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink

For the last few months, I've been working on/maintaining a Java web service which communicates with an Oracle 11.2.0.1 database, using EclipseLink as its ORM.

Last week, the webservice suddenly stopped working entirely. It took me a week to find the cause of the problem: The first time a certain named query's `getResultList()`-method is called, nothing happens afterwards - no debug output, no exception, nothing. It seemed like the method just did not return anything and blocked everything else.
To try and figure out, whether it really was the query causing the problem, I wrote a minimal program which just connects to the DB, and executes the query (without using an ORM system). Interestingly, I could reproduce the behavior.

The query in the following code is about the same as the named query I found out to cause the problems:

```
PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, COLUMN_F FROM TABLE_A WHERE ((COLUMN_F = ?) AND ((COLUMN_A = ?) AND (COLUMN_E = ?))) ORDER BY COLUMN_C");
statement1.setInt(1, 2389);
statement1.setDate(2, new Date(1432001201233L));
statement1.setDate(3, new Date(1432052300513L));
System.out.println("Getting result set");
ResultSet resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery();
System.out.println("...got it"); // Never reached
```

This query has been used for months and always worked - until last week.

I found out, that if I remove the parentheses in the query, everything works as expected (in my vanilla testing application as well as using a named query in JPA/EclipseLink):

```
"SELECT ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, COLUMN_F FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_F = ? AND COLUMN_A = ? AND COLUMN_E = ? ORDER BY COLUMN_C"
```

It seems to me, that the parentheses in the first query, though they don't really clarify the semantics of the query, are valid SQL and should not cause any errors. 
Executing the query in SQL Developer results in the expected behavior (i.e. a list of tuples matching the criteria, if they exist).

So my question is: What am I missing? Why did the query work and then suddenly stopped? And why doesn't it cause ANY exception or error or something along those lines, but just stalls the execution of the application?

Comment: do login onto database server and look at top (or process monitor) and check cpu usage to see the really database is doing something. You can also check v$sql_plan to check execution plan. I think problem will be somewhere else - removing additional parenthesis is trivial algebraic transformation and Oracle has not problems with that.

Comment: maybe your problem is data related. it takes long to execute only for particular values of bind variables.

Comment: If it would be data related or a problem with the load of the DB server it would not work either when using SQLDeveloper, or am I wrong?

Comment: are you sure that you use same values for bind variables in both cases?

Comment: Yes, and the original query worked with none of the bindings I tried...

Comment: then you really need some tool which will display execution plan of the running Oracle session (session browser). I think even SQLDeveloper can do that.